# ...начинают(,) как раз(,) когда

Tags: пунктуация

Вопрос о запятой во фразах типа "*Обычно крики о близкой победе начинаются(,) **как раз(,) когда** всё идет совсем плохо*".

Я так долго думал, в каком месте нужна запятая и почему, что грешным делом вообще забыл её поставить. Фраза немного изменена, у меня была подлиннее, но так понятнее суть вопроса.

Есть смутное подозрение, что это что-то типа расчленяемого союза, позволяющего использовать двоякую пунктуацию, но не нашел подтверждения.

Answer (score 5):

Правильно:

*Обычно крики о близкой победе начинаются, **как раз когда** всё идет совсем плохо*.

Здесь ***как раз***  –  частица со значением '= именно, точно', подчёркивающая **последующие слова**. Запятая ставится перед частицей, после неё  не ставится.

См. [**ПАС:**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)

> **§ 116.** Если перед простым подчинительным союзом стоят
>   усилительно-ограничительные слова (частицы, союзы или их сочетания,
>   вводные слова) *особенно, даже, в частности, в том числе, в
>   особенности, а именно, а также, а (но) только, **как раз**, лишь,
>   исключительно, только* и др., то запятая ставится перед ними, а не
>   перед союзом…

Comment: Спасибо. Но вы знаете, было бы убедительно, кабы не одно но. Я не вижу тут значения усилительно-ограничительной частицы. Более того, я боюсь, что такой подход исказит смысл. У Лопатина пример однозначен - значение "вовремя", оно и в самой фразе есть. Но у меня-то замена на "точно тогда" изменит весь смысл фразы, его причинно-следственную определенность. "Обычно крики о близкой победе как раз начинаются, когда всё идет совсем плохо" - смысл тот же (почти), но "как раз" не относится к когда. Я не говорю, что отвергаю сходу вашу версию объяснения, но что-то пока я ей не проникся.

Answer (score 2):

Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят *усилительные частицы **как раз, только, лишь, исключительно*** и т. п., то запятая ставится перед ними вопреки интонации (при чтении пауза перед ними не делается).
[как раз когда, только если, исключительно чтобы, лишь когда...]

***Обычно крики о близкой победе начинаются, как раз когда всё идет совсем плохо.***

*Катя вышла из столовой, **как раз когда** мы шагнули друг к другу через какие-то чемоданы.*
*Он приехал вовремя, **как раз когда** должны были начаться занятия.*
 *Перед ними предстал овраг, **лишь когда** рассеялся туман.*

[**Запятая перед усилительно-ограничительными словами**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC/)

Answer (score 1):

Я согласен со slava1947, здесь **запятая нужна перед словами "как раз"**. Но ваш комментарий проливает свет на причины ваших сомнений.

> Но у меня-то замена на "точно тогда" изменит весь смысл фразы, его
>   причинно-следственную определенность.

Да, у "как раз" есть несколько значений (или если принципиально - одно значение с разными "подзначениями"). И не все они имеют одинаковые синонимические ряды. Я понимаю, о чем вы пишете, хотя и не сказал бы что смысл фразы меняется существенно. "Как раз" может относиться либо к последующему слову (и быть усилительной или "усилительно-ограничительной" частицей только для него), либо действовать более глобально, на всю фразу, приобретая частично свойство вводного слова. Лопатин при разборе этого правила примеры для этого и подобных слов дает только на первый случай (ещё один случай - "как раз" в значении сказуемого - опускаем сразу). Но всё дело в том, что правило о которой пишет **slava1947** оно совершенно формально, пунктуация зависит только от самого наличия сочетания "как раз" + союз (или союзное слово). Точно так же отнесение к "усилительно-ограничительным словам" совершенно формально. Нет грамматических или пунктуационных причин выделять специальное значение того плана, о котором вы пишете. Да и смысл, как уже сказал, меняется не настолько существенно, чтобы о том говорить.

Поэтому с чистой совестью рекомендую не заморачиваться с поисками особых значений и авторской пунктуации и делать все по шаблону, предписанному правилами. **Все равно ведь для запятой перед "как раз" нет никаких оснований**, да и ваш смысл она отнюдь не передала бы. Если уж совсем глаз не принимает, перестройте фразу, как вы сами это и предлагали.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно крики о близкой победе начинаются, как раз когда всё идет совсем плохо.

1) Частица КАК РАЗ имеет здесь скорее выделительное значение: ИМЕННО КОГДА.

2) Иногда союз КОГДА может иметь дополнительный оттенок условия или причины, например: "Когда (= если)  идешь в дальнюю дорогу, то уже не разбираешь погоды" (В. Арсеньев).

Можно предложить другой вариант: Обычно крики о близкой победе начинаются как раз тогда, когда всё идет совсем плохо.

Грамматика здесь более сложная, но смысл (значение не времени, а  условия или причины) выражен яснее.